# c++ : calling constructors via curly braces?

Tags: c++, constructor, scope, return

```
class A 
{
    int value_;
    public:
    A(int value):value_(value){}
};

A get_a1(int value)
{
    return A(value);
}

A get_a2(int value)
{
    return {value};
}


int main()
{
    A a1 = get_a1(1);
    A a2 = get_a2(2);
}
```

What is the difference between `get_a1()` and `get_a2()`, if any ?

How is `return {value};` called ? (I guess "calling constructors via curly braces" is not the proper way to refers to this)

Comment: Close enough, I guess. It's a "braced-init-list", according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization
I'm not fluent in standartese, so I will leave the full answer for someone who feels like getting into the nitty-gritty.

Comment: Two differences that come to mind is if you had `long value` instead it could warn you in `get_a2` or if `A` had a `std::initializer_list` constructor `get_a1` and `get_a2` would use different constructors.

Comment: fwiw, `return value;` is also fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case, there is simply no difference. But if you modify your code a bit, there will be a visible difference!

First of all, you can construct your type in different ways, all described here: [initilization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization)

The difference come in, if your class provides also a constructor which takes a `std::initializer_list`.

See the following code modified/extended to show the difference:

```
class A 
{   
    public:
        A(int value):value_(value){ std::cout << "int" << std::endl;}
        A(const std::initializer_list<int>& ){ std::cout << "list" << std::endl;}
        void print()
        {   
            std::cout << value_ << std::endl;
        }   
    private:
        int value_;
};  

A get_a1(int value)
{   
    std::cout << "()" << std::endl;
    return A(value);
}   

A get_a2(int value)
{
    std::cout << "{}" << std::endl;
    return {value};
}


int main()
{   
    A a1 = get_a1(1);
    a1.print();
    A a2 = get_a2(2);
    a2.print();
}
```

If you run that prog, you will see that using `{}` will call the constructor with `std::initializer_list` and using `()` will use your `int` constructor.

Why is described here in the standard:

> §13.3.1.7 [over.match.list]/p1:
>
> When objects of non-aggregate class type `T` are list-initialized
>   (8.5.4), overload resolution selects the constructor in two phases:
>
> - Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors (8.5.4) of the class `T` and the argument list consists of
>     the initializer list as a single argument.
> - If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all
>     the constructors of the class `T` and the argument list consists of
>     the elements of the initializer list.
>
> If the initializer list has no elements and `T` has a default
>   constructor, the first phase is omitted. In copy-list-initialization,
>   if an `explicit` constructor is chosen, the initialization is
>   ill-formed.

In addition, initializer list constructors do not allow narrowing!

> §8.5.4 List-initialization
>
> (3.4) Otherwise, if T is a class type, constructors are considered. The applicable
>   constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen through overload
>   resolution ([over.match], [over.match.list]). If a narrowing conversion
>   (see below) is required to convert any of the arguments, the 
>   program is ill-formed.

Comment: If we are extending OPs example, there are more possible difference, e.g. left-to-right sequenced evaluation if there are multiple elements in the list and different behavior if the class is an aggregate. Because OP wrote `{value}` instead of `A{value}` there is also a potential difference in an additional move construction pre-C++17. And I am sure I am forgetting some stuff.

Comment: @walnut You are absolutely right. My idea was to give a bit more background where the difference can be observed without modifying to much. If answer only the original code example, the simple answer is also given: No difference... :-)